# Prevent display of "shared on Google+" in YouTube

Tags: youtube, google-plus

When I share some video from YouTube on Google+, on YouYube, under this video, appears a comment that I've shared it on Google+. Is it possible not to display those comments on YouTube? How can I turn it off?

Comment: Can you disable comments entirely on the video?

Answer (score 1):

That is the exact same problem I have. There is no solution, but I have an workaround:

1. My G+ profile is +MoviesVladan
2. I have a page built on that profile: +VladanmoviesBlogspotccc
3. My Youtube channel is www.youtube.com/user/vladanmovies
4. Youtube channel is linked to PAGE. NOT to profile!
5. Comments settings for channel and clips are "Only approved"
   (5a. For a while I kept my "profile" banned from my channel, which prevents comments 
   from showing on YT, but can not prevent "profile" from sharing and commenting.)

If I share as "profile", they are all held for approval and I never approve them.
If I share from page, they do show as comments under the clip, but those I manually remove, from the clip page on YT. That way shares stay on G+, but comments are not visible on YT.